# Shopping cart integration with codeIgniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, e-commerce, shopping-cart

Can anyone please suggest me any open source shopping cart library which can be integrated with codeIgniter with support for stores, discounts, promotions, order management and payment gateways.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: http://haseydesign.com/flexi-cart/lite_library/features

Comment: @nevermind - Does it support store features. I mean, can I use this cart for multiple stores ?

Comment: Not sure, i wouldn't say so... however, i would rather choose OpenCart (or some other open source script; hovever, i like open cart, relatively easy code to understand/modify it) for e-commerce site?

Comment: Yes, for an e-commerce site. But most of the things are in place (implemented in codeIgniter), I just need to enhance my shopping cart and quickly. So I am opting for some codeigniter based lib.

Answer (score 0):

http://gocartdv.com
The goal of GoCart is not to add an enormous number of features, but to build an easy to use, easy to customize shopping cart.